# JavaScript - How to insert HTML codes in the middle of the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find the mid point of the content and insert a block of HTML codes after the `<br>` tag or `</p>` tag so the sentence doesn't get split.

I can find the middle point of the content, but I am not sure how to find the closest `<br>` tag or `</p>` tag and insert HTML code.

Here is the code that I have so far. **JS Fiddle** (http://jsfiddle.net/sunflowersh/BHHFZ/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var content = $(".content");

var contentLength = $('.content').text().length;

var midLength = parseInt(contentLength / 2);

midLength.closest("<br>, </p>, <br/>").append("Ad Codes Come Here");

});
```

Comment: `closest()` is not what you want. It browses DOM tree, trying to find a parent matching a given selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that you're not the one controlling the content, or it would be p tags instead of them and breaks all mixed up. This will search out p and br inside the content, count them, and place the ad after mid point of their combined length.

```
var content = $('.content').find('p, br');
var midLength = parseInt(content.length/2);
content.eq(midLength).after("Ad Codes Come Here");
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/BHHFZ/20/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the clean code.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! This should be recursive, and you can add anything else you would need to as well, like `pre` or `blockquotes`, depending on the curcumstances.

Comment: Perfect solution. I was looking for that only. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work if you can modify the source to use `<p>` tags for each paragraph instead of sometimes using `<br>`:

```
content.children().each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    contLength += $this.text().length;

    if(contLength >= midLength){
         $this.after("<div class='added'>EXTRA STUFF ADDED HERE</div>");   
         return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BHHFZ/13/

Comment: Thank you for the solution. As we can't control the tag to be all </p>, though I like this solution, we can't use it.. Voted 1 for the great solution thou. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Substring your content into two parts:

The first one from 0 to middle.
The second one from middle to last

Then find the first position of the `<br>` tag in the second string. If this is enough then you're done.

Else if you want to find the nearest `<br>` from both sides, then search as well for the position of `<br>` in the first string but this time the last one and not the first. Compare the distance between 0 and `<br>` in the second part / and the length of the string with the position of `<br>` in the first part. The smaller means the closer, then add whatever you want at the position of the `br` (+it's length if you want to insert your element after it)

Comment: Wrap code in your answers in  ` ` marks so it displays properly.  Particulary html tags.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind breaking your text up into paragraphs, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = $(".content");
    insertAt = content.children('p') === 0 ? 0 : Math.ceil(content.children('p').length / 2);
    content.children('p').eq(insertAt).before("<p style='color: red'>mid-point</p>");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HHeLw/2/

Comment: If we can control the tags in the content, this is an ideal solution. Unfortunately, we can't control the tags in the content. Thanks for the solution. voted 1.